# Get mysql other stored procedure to new store procedure data

Tags: mysql

I would like to get results of mysql stored procedure into other stored procedure and insert into temporary table.

Example:

Result of stored procedure 1

```
ID NAME SEX
1  A    M
2  B   F
3  C   M
```

Code in stored procedure 2

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TBL1;
INSERT INTO TBL1 (call storeprocedure1('));
```

How can we get all data in stored procedure 1 insert into temporary table in stored procedure2 ?

Comment: It is not possible. Even with functions it is not possible. Another option is load `TBL1` inside the `storeprocedure1` itself.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you still can't do that in Mysql.

A possible solution is to insert into a temporary table from the first stored procedure and use it in the second.

```sql
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_result
    (`ID` int, `NAME` varchar(1), `SEX` varchar(1));

CREATE PROCEDURE sp_one()
  INSERT INTO tmp_result
  SELECT 1 id, 'A' name, 'M' sex UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'B', 'F' UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'C', 'M';

CREATE PROCEDURE sp_two()
  SELECT * FROM tmp_result;

CALL sp_one();
CALL sp_two();

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_result;
```

Comment: Did it help? Do you need more help with your question?